# How do I pass the argument correctly in Python

Tags: python

I have a Problem with my a little script. I want to open my program with an argument (`--color BLUE`).

The color is defined like this:

```
BLUE = bytearray(b'\x00\x00\xff')
```

The parser looks like this:

```
common_parser.add_argument('--color', dest='color', action='store', required=False, default=BLUE, help='set the color')
```

When I now start the script with the argument `--color YELLOW` it only read the "Y" and works with it. It does not point at the bytearray. How can I pass it correctly?

Comment: Not an answer to why you only get "Y" for "YELLOW", but what you are doing is probably not what you want to do: when the user uses --color YELLOW, you will get the color as the *string* "YELLOW", whereas if he does not pass anything, you will get your `bytearray`. I would suggest that you map the colors to their `bytearray` (`colors = {"BLUE": bytearray(…),…}`), and have `default="BLUE"` (a string).

Comment: @EOL How is that not an answer? Should I remove my answer? :-)

Comment: The problem in the question is that `--color YELLOW` "only reads the Y". Your solution is fine, though, as this a good answer to the task at hand. :)

Comment: @Lukas Kuhl: What do you mean by "it only read the "Y" and works with it"? When you do `prog.py --color YELLOW`, you correctly get `Namespace(color='YELLOW')` for the parsed arguments. In any case, you want to do what @Reut Sharabani and I suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a dictionary of colors and their corresponding objects:

```
COLORS = {
    'BLUE': bytearray(b'\x00\x00\xff'),
    'GREEN': bytearray(b'\x00\xff\x00'),
    'RED': bytearray(b'\xff\x00\x00')
}
```

Change the `add_argument` call to:

```
common_parser.add_argument('--color', dest='color', required=False, default="BLUE", help='set the color')
```

Now you can use the argument to find the color by key (both are strings):

```
color = COLORS[args.color]
```

Where `args` are the parsed command-line arguments from `argparse`.

Comment: @ReutSharabani: You do not need the `type=str`: this is the default (I edited your answer again).

Comment: @EOL Does it do type-checking without it? Also, I add it because it's self-documenting about what's expected for code readers.

Comment: @LukasKuhl , if this answers your question you can accept the answer.

Comment: @ReutSharabani `argparse` does not make any conversion of the arguments, by default: since they are characters, in the command line, they remain characters (so, no type checking is needed, since the parsed arguments *are* strings, by default). I also consider that writing `type=str` is actually anti-documenting: it implies that this is not the default, which sends the wrong signal about `add_argument()`—and can make people take the habit of writing code which is unnecessarily longer.